# Consulta mysql con variable de formulario php

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios, subconsultas

Error: [image: ERROR MOSTRADO POR PANTALLA]

Parte del código PHP:

```
//Habiendo conexión, la base de datos puede no existir o ...
mysqli_select_db ($conexion, $basedatos) or die ("No se encuentra la base de datos");
mysqli_set_charset ($conexion,"utf-8");

//Haremos una consulta a la base de datos para mostrar el contenido
$consulta = "select cod, nombre from familia";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

echo "<h1>Consulta noticias</h1>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<form action='mostrar.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<select name='producto'>";
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    echo "<option value='" . $fila['cod'] . "'>" . $fila['nombre'] . " </option>";
}
echo "</select><p><input type='submit' name='Enviar'/></p></form>";
```

Selección del producto en la base de datos:

[image: RESULTADO DE LA SELECCIÓN]

Parte del código PHP a mostrar:

```
//Habiendo conexión, la base de datos puede no existir o ...

mysqli_select_db ($conexion, $basedatos) or die ("No se encuentra la base de datos");
mysqli_set_charset ($conexion,"utf-8");
$fam = $_POST['producto'];
echo "$fam";
//Haremos una consulta a la base de datos para mostrar el contenido
// SOSPECHO QUE EL ERROR ESTÁ EN LA VARIABLE $fam
$consulta = 'select cod, nombre_corto, pvp from productos where ' . $fam . '=familia';
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    print ("El codigo es " . $fila['cod'] . " el nombre corto es " . $fila['nombre_corto'] . " el pvp es " . $fila['pvp'] ."<br>");
}
```

Comment: En el documento mostrar.php, haz un var_dump en $fam para saber si te esta llegando lo que eliges en el documento anterior

Comment: Solucionado. Gracias por los comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con mysqli_fetch_array sin embargo el error esta en la consulta:

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo.

```
$consulta = "select cod, nombre_corto, pvp FROM productos where $fam ='familia'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach ($row as $rows){
        echo "El codigo es " . $rows['cod'] . " el nombre corto es " . $rows['nombre_corto'] . " el pvp es " . $rows['pvp'] ."<br>";
    }
```

> Cuando usas comillas dobles `""` no es necesario concatenar las variables.

En segunda instancia te recomiendo usar PDO, por seguridad, fluidez, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tras realizar los cambios propuestos el error sigue estando. Ahora salen los siguientes errores: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BD\formu\mostrar.php on line 27

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\BD\formu\mostrar.php on line 29

Answer (score 1):

Modifiqué las siguientes lineas:

```
$consulta = "select cod, nombre_corto, pvp from producto where familia='$fam'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Añadiendo "or die(mysqli_error($conexion));" pude visualizar el error y solucionarlo.

Gracias por las respuestas.

Answer (score -1):

familia tiene que ir entre comillas ella misma también es decir:

```
$consulta = 'select cod, nombre_corto, pvp from productos where ' . $fam . '="familia"';
```

Pero a mi personalmente me gusta mas sin concatenar todo dentro de un string de comillas dobles y para otros strings o variables dentro uso las simples, es decir:

```
$consulta = "select cod, nombre_corto, pvp from productos where $fam = 'familia'";
```

Y tambien añado que esta mal la sentencia `set_charset`, utf8 es sin guion, es decir:

```
mysqli_set_charset ($conexion,"utf8");
```

Comment: Buenas noches, modifiqué el código y sigue dando el mismo error, probé todas las posibles combinaciones de comillas simples y dobles, pero sigue dando error. No entiendo porqué falla, puesto que el valor de la variable la recoge correctamente y la visualizo, pero no realiza la consulta con esta. Gracias.